# Is it possible to add a custom menu item to built-in apps like addressbook, safari, Fileviewer etc in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, mobile-safari, jailbreak

I need to add a custom menu item to the built in apps in iPhone. Is it possible to add a custom menu item to built-in apps like addressbook, safari, Fileviewer etc?

Comment: This would only be possible on jailbroken devices, and even then would be extremely difficult to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: No.

Long answer: Without a jailbroken device, you won't be able to touch anything else besides files in your own "sandbox". You can probably accomplish a similar task by utilizing the jailbreak framework [MobileSubstrate](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/MobileSubstrate).

Answer (score 1):

No. The most integration you can get with private apps is any of them that allow you to export a file, you can register your app to open these. (like mail attachments and etc)